# Can a DOM element handle both keyup and input event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In an application I have a text input elements with an input handler. There is a special action I'd like to do on backspace so I added a keyup handler to handle this case. It doesn't gets called unless the field is empty - apparently when the input handler is called it suppresses the keyup handler.

I could probably rewrite the code using the keyup handler for everything but that would involve reproducing proper handling of pasting and other keys (delete, enter, tab, etc.), which I'd rather not do.

This is on chrome but I tested it on firefox and safari too and get the same behavior so it must be expected, but I can't find it documented. The following code demonstrates the issue. When loaded as is and text is entered only the input handler is called. When the field is empty the keyup handler is called. If the input handler is deleted then of course the keyup handler is called on every key press.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function setup() {
      document.getElementById("xxx").addEventListener("input", (ev) => alert("input"));
      document.getElementById("xxx").addEventListener("keyup", (ev) => alert("keyup"));
      }
      window.addEventListener("load", () => setup());
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    test handlers: <input type="text" id="xxx" />
  </body>
</html>
```

*(sample edited to use addEventListener rather than onevent)*

The workaround I'm thinking about now is using a keydown event, which is called, but I'd like to understand why it has this behavior.

Comment: Yes, but stop using 1998-style `on...` HTML attributes, and start using proper JS event listening. Have your JS get your element, and then use `addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler)` to bind any and all listeners you need. (and remember to load your JS with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` to make sure it loads independently of your page code, and doesn't execute until the DOM is ready for queries.

Comment: I'm not sure why they conflict when you use inline event handlers, but it works as desired with `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, I did that for simplicity, it was quicker to type. My actual code does it with addEventListener, and it doesn't change the example. I've edited the

Comment: @Barmar No, it still doesn't, I changed the example code to use addEventListener and get the same behavior.

Comment: Always remember to show _your actual code_. Reducing is fine, rewriting is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both getting called every time only the one alert is invalidating the other call as you can see if you change the alert to a log

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  test handlers: <input type="text" oninput="console.log('input')" onkeyup="alert('keyup')" />
</body>
</html>
```

or if you set a timeout

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  test handlers: <input type="text" oninput="setTimeout(()=>alert('input'),1000)" onkeyup="alert('keyup')" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is expected as a backspace is changing the input and a keyup is when a key is released and the keyup is released when the alert is in the window

Comment: Why does the first snippet alerts `Keyup` even if I was typing some letters??

Comment: did you release the key when you were typing? if so the key went up and it must send an alert as per the listener. But if when the key is released we are really in the alert window then there is no call on this page but on the alert where there is no listener.

Comment: Thank you, this is certainly what is happening.in the sample code, and probably will explain what I'm seeing in the application code.